# Crashlytics does not work in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, crashlytics

After the project was launched, the application was not added to the dashboard.

I launched the project on an android SDK with the same package name. After that, the application was added to the dashboard.

Events such as "sendCustomEvent" work. But the crash still is not sent. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send a crash. It was necessary to remove the application using adb.
adb uninstall "name.package"

Answer (score 1):

Todd from Fabric here. Corona is not currently supported by our SDKs due to the way it builds projects. Barring official support, I'd love to hear if any one has gotten this up and running and the steps they used to do so. Thanks!